# Windows 10 Action Center Notifications - Chrome Missing

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, notifications, action-center

Chrome Notifications do not show up in the action center. I have checked for similar questions being asked but I've yet to come across a resolution to this issue. Notifications are presented, but when the notification retracts it does not end up in the Action Center. "Enable Native Notifications" is enabled in chrome://flags. Chrome is missing from the Notifications & Actions listing for "Senders". What is in there is Auto Play, Battery Saver, Cisco AnyConnect User Interface, Outlook, Settings, Software Center.  I can confirm that notifications from those senders do show up in Action Center. I should note this is a work laptop which is joined to a domain (but is only "on the domain" when VPN is connected) so I can only assume this a GPO. If it helps, the OS is Windows 10 x64 1709 16299.125. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you look under Google Chrome?   That is where Chrome Notifications are on my machine.  Chrome also has some of its own notifications (like some other software) that do not harmonize with Windows 10 Notitications

Comment: As stated, Chrome's notifications do show up, they just don't get put into the action center.

Comment: I am going to go ahead and assume here that the issue is my OS is severely out of date and that this issue is tied to that. I see no related GPO and manually adding the reg entry "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Chrome" with dword rank = 1 does not do anything. I'll try running windows update (via corp vpn only...) and then see if that helps.

Comment: @John - 1709; The author indicates that in their question.  This behavior has more to do with a group policy than the version of Windows 10 they are forced to use.

Comment: James - I missed the version in your post, sorry. Try updating as V1709 is out of support

Comment: This might be a dead issue for me then. My work's domain policy controls the updates. All updates applied but still stuck with 1709. I still feel like this is something that could be fixed with the right registry tweaks but who knows.